# Is it possible to remove the gap between the caption buttons (minimize, restore...) in Windows XP/Vista?

Tags: .net, winapi, devexpress

I needed to remove the gap between the buttons while creating a skin using Devexpress skin editor. I couldn't find such an option. Then I thought it can be done by code but I couldn't find an answer, even using the Windows API.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no API to control the placement of those buttons.

You could subclass them and force them to change position, but that's a big pain. Also users will be subliminally disturbed.

Better you should turn them off entirely and write a custom form with custom buttons.